# Read ~/.bash_profile but not /etc/profile

Tags: bash

I noticed that you can prevent reading `/etc/profile` by running

```
bash --noprofile
```

However this also stops `~/.bash_profile` from being read. Can Bash be invoked in such a way as to read `~/.bash_profile` but not `/etc/profile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the options --noprofile and --rcfile file_name where file_name is the config file you want read, e.g:

```
bash --noprofile --rcfile ~/.bash_profile
```

Well... somebody didn't like this answer, but it appears to be exactly what was desired:

`--noprofile` causes all normal rc files to **not** be read.
`--rcfile <some file>` causes the specified file to be read instead. This can certainly be the user's .bash_profile as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do add in ~/.bashrc file

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
        . ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The login shell will always read `/etc/profile`, which allows the system admin to set environment variables and paths for all users.

If you are the only user and this is your system you are free to edit or remove /etc/profile if you wish.

Comment: No... --noprofile from the manpage: "Do no read either the system-wide startup file /etc/profile or any of the personal initialization files ..."